# How can I add a class to an element from an array on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array of elements. I want when I hover on any element from this array to add a class to said element. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each item in the array and an event listener for `mouseover` which adds the class.

```js
const array = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const classToAdd = 'red';
array.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  e.classList.add(classToAdd);
}))
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple elements with different ids or class you can try this.

```js
let elements = ['#hud-menu', '#hud-intro', '.hud-shop', '.hud-settings'];

document.querySelectorAll(elements).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    element.classList.add('blue');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="hud-menu">Hud Menu</div><br>
<div id="hud-intro">Hud Intro</div><br>
<div class="hud-shop">Hud Shop</div><br>
<div class="hud-settings">Hud Settings</div>
```

And just in case if you want to remove the class when you stop hovering over an element you can use `mouseout` like the example below.

```js
let elements = ['#hud-menu', '#hud-intro', '.hud-shop', '.hud-settings'];

// Add class on mouseover
document.querySelectorAll(elements).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    element.classList.add('blue');
  });
});

// Remove class on mouseout
document.querySelectorAll(elements).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    element.classList.remove('blue');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="hud-menu">Hud Menu</div><br>
<div id="hud-intro">Hud Intro</div><br>
<div class="hud-shop">Hud Shop</div><br>
<div class="hud-settings">Hud Settings</div>
```